# How to write a bison grammar for WDI?

Tags: html, c, parsing, grammar, bison

I need some help in bison grammar construction.

*From my another question:*
I'm trying to make a meta-language for writing markup code (such as xml and html) which can be directly embedded into C/C++ code.
Here is a simple sample written in this language, I call it WDI (Web Development Interface):

```
 /*
  * Simple wdi/html sample source code
  */
 #include <mySite>

 string name = "myName";
 string toCapital(string str);

 html
 {
  head {
   title { mySiteTitle; }
   link(rel="stylesheet", href="style.css");
  }
  body(id="default") {
   // Page content wrapper
   div(id="wrapper", class="some_class") {
    h1 { "Hello, " + toCapital(name) + "!"; }

    // Lists post
    ul(id="post_list") {
     for(post in posts) {
      li { a(href=post.getID()) { post.tilte; } }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Basically it is a C source with a user-friendly interface for html.
As you can see the traditional tag-based style is substituted by C-like, with blocks delimited by curly braces.
I need to build an interpreter to translate this code to html and posteriorly insert it into C, so that it can be compiled. The C part stays intact.
Inside the wdi source it is not necessary to use prints, every return statement will be used for output (in printf function).
The program's output will be clean html code.

So, for example a heading 1 tag would be transformed like this:

```
h1 { "Hello, " + toCapital(name) + "!"; }
// would become:
printf("<h1>Hello, %s!</h1>", toCapital(name));
```

My main goal is to create an interpreter to translate wdi source to html like this:

`tag(attributes) {content}` => `<tag attributes>content</tag>`

Secondly, html code returned by the interpreter has to be inserted into C code with printfs. Variables and functions that occur inside wdi should also be sorted in order to use them as printf parameters (the case of toCapital(name) in sample source).

Here are my flex/bison files:

```
id        [a-zA-Z_]([a-zA-Z0-9_])*
number    [0-9]+
string    \".*\"

%%

{id} {
        yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
        return(ID);
    }

{number} {
        yylval.number = atoi(yytext);
        return(NUMBER);
    }

{string} {
        yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
        return(STRING);
    }

"(" { return(LPAREN); }
")" { return(RPAREN); }
"{" { return(LBRACE); }
"}" { return(RBRACE); }
"=" { return(ASSIGN); }
"," { return(COMMA);  }
";" { return(SEMICOLON); }

\n|\r|\f { /* ignore EOL */ }
[ \t]+   { /* ignore whitespace */ }
.        { /* return(CCODE); Find C source */ }

%%
```

---

```
%start wdi
%token LPAREN RPAREN LBRACE RBRACE ASSIGN COMMA SEMICOLON CCODE QUOTE

%union
{
    int number;
    char *string;
}

%token <string> ID STRING
%token <number> NUMBER

%%
wdi
    : /* empty */
    | blocks
    ;

blocks
    : block
    | blocks block
    ;

block
    : head SEMICOLON
    | head body
    ;

head
    : ID
    | ID
    attributes
    ;

attributes
    : LPAREN RPAREN
    | LPAREN attribute_list RPAREN
    ;

attribute_list
    : attribute
    | attribute COMMA attribute_list
    ;

attribute
    : key ASSIGN value
    ;

key
    : ID {$$=$1}
    ;

value
    : STRING {$$=$1}
    /*| NUMBER*/
    /*| CCODE*/
    ;

body
    : LBRACE content RBRACE
    ;

content
    : /* */
    | blocks
    | STRING SEMICOLON
    | NUMBER SEMICOLON
    | CCODE
    ;

%%
```

I am having difficulties on defining a proper grammar for the language, specially in splitting WDI and C code . I just started learning language processing techniques so I need some orientation.
Could someone correct my code or give some examples of what is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: you ask for corrections for your code - can you perhaps tell us what is wrong with it? Does it refuse to compile, throw a runtime error, or accept / reject the wrong things? Some clarification would help us to help you.

Comment: It does work! I mean the grammar accepts WDI source. But I Think this code is incomplete. I don't know how to manage token variables and use them later, for example...

Comment: If that's the case, you'll want to do some searching for how to implement a symbol table. That's the data structure you'll need to store the tokens (along with any inherited or synthesized attributes for them) for use later on.

Comment: Do you want to generate C Code, or have an interpreter for WDI which evaluates the file at run time?

Comment: My main goal is to create WDI to C compiler. There should be two components in the compiler: a symbol table constructor, which would define syntactic/semantics rules and C code generator.
I also considered creating a separate WDI interpreter (WDI to html) for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to *parse* C code and embedded WDI code, you're in for a hard ride.  LALR(1) parser generators (including Bison) are notoriously bad at parsing C, let alone things more complicated than C (meaning C + WDI).

Either you will have to:

a) learn how to make Bison parse C by tangling parsing and symbol table construction (meaning, go struggle with GNU GCC to see how they did it ),

b) Switch to a stronger parser generator such as a GLR parser generator (which Bison has an option for) and learn how to deal with ambiguous grammars and how to resolve them,

or

c) design WDI as a kind of island grammer, in which the goal is to pick out the WDI code and leave everything that is not WDI as opaque strings (in your case destined to be output as presumed C code).   This latter approach is much easier, and is roughly what all the web page languages (ASP, PHP, JSP ...) do.   The upside is that this is much easier, and you only have to write the grammar for WDI itself and a lexer that will pick up everything that is not WDI as an abitrary string.  The down side is that you wont' be able to make WDI and C interact nicely/and/or check the validity of a WDI program with your parser.
See this SO question for some more background:

[Island grammar antlr3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561249/island-grammar-antlr3)

This would be easier if you go learn about compiler technology in more detail before you started this project.